# A tedious beginning

Tags: cipher, story

Someone keeps sending messages. They seem to be constant on my computer, and there is a answer box on it. I can’t open tabs or anything because of it. The message goes as such:

E96 BF:4< 3C@H? 7@I ;F>AD @G6C `b =2KJ 5@8D

There’s another message too. It says that I’m the forty seventh to be trolled in this manner. They also said that I should feel remorse, and that it should make me feel like jumping into a honeycomb. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You are the 47th to be trolled? Hmm... plugging this into ROT47 gives me this weird little pangram:

> The quick brown fox jumps over 13 lazy dogs.

Also, I suspect 'remorse' hints me at Morse code, and 'honeycomb' seems to hint me at... hexadecimal, I suppose? Bit hard to continue, though.

EDIT: I think the 13 in the pangram may tell us to apply ROT13, a comment's best friend. Alas, I could not go any further.

Comment: … I did not intend for that lil’ Easter egg. Thanks for letting me notice!

Comment: Also, ROT47 is involved, and you might be correct about some other things as well… I didn’t call it tedious for nothing :)

Comment: Well, it has been about a week now. Any hints?

Comment: Yes. A rot code, hexadecimal, and Morse code are involved, but I’m not telling the order. This is why I  called it tedious, because it’s annoying.

Comment: This is what I have intended! :)